# SWIPL PROLOG as JSON Query

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a knowledge base represented as PROLOG facts.

I run swipl commands in a pipeline, each step emitting a new set of facts.

I append the new facts to the old knowledge base using `bash` commands.

Now, I want to do this same thing using a knowledge base represented as some kind of JSON.

Questions:

1. How best to represent the facts (triples) as JSON?
2. How to read all of the facts in?
3. How to query the read-in factbase?
4. How to write out all of the new facts (or, how to write out the complete augmented factbase)?

I know how to write queries in PROLOG (3).  Maybe question (2) becomes "how to read all of the JSON facts and convert them to internal form?"

A simple example follows
fb.pl

```
triple(father,john,george).
triple(father,paul,ringo).
```

queries.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env swipl
:- initialization query.

query:-
    consult(user),
    triple(father,paul,F),
    write(user_output,F),
    halt.
```

bash command line:

```
$ chmod +x query.pl
$ ./query.pl -q <fb.pl 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: No.  ATM I am using raw triples (functors with 2 args).  I will change my mind given a good argument, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I am building a diagram-to-python transpiler.  I am using swipl to infer information (parse, semantics) about the diagram.  As such, I get to start with a clean slate.  JSON is a stepping stone, if it's easy-enough to write/read.

Comment: Using SWI-Prolog with JSON is great once you figure it out. In an project of mine Prolog facts are converted to JSON for use with [Cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/). Take a look at converting SWI-Prolog dicts to json predicates. ([ref](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=json))

Comment: You might be better off asking this on the [SWI-Prolog forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/) as there one can have a proper discussion.